# how do I get a nice Coding-Style and easy maintenance when using translation maps in an Java Enterprise App?

Tags: java, coding-style, code-formatting

Imagine that you are editing a big back office Enterprise Java app, where other people might poke around years from now. That means you have to keep the code clean and easy to understand, performance might not be the #1 priority.

There is a module that needs to

1. Extract data from objects
2. Map data parameters, for example SE -> Sweden [this only applies and is used in this module, for now]
3. Send these new parameters to somewhere (for example via email/xml)

For a small set of data, then i'd use a small HashMap, but the custom table of data that has to be transformed has grown to 3 HashMaps with ~100 elements in some. I have them in a file called Translater.Java

and there I got a method:

```
public String getCountryCode(String country) {
    return countryCodes.get(country);
}
```

which is initiated with

```
countryCodes = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("Andorra", "AD");
    put("Afghanistan", "AF");
    ...
}};
```

it looks ugly! But my choices seem to be:

1. Make a database table in a new database, which would add another layer of obfuscation when a coder just wants to see what maps to what. It is also not needed to ever change this data, and if so its better done as a code change since the db is not source code controlled! (we use hibernate)
2. Store this static data as a config file, the application uses a database table for configuration options, this would add to the maintenance.
3. Use the config database table to store this, that would work but could also make the rest of the configuration options harder to find since the other types of data in the configuration table are relatively small and cohesive.

Comment: How is likely that a country code is changed or added?

Comment: maybe once in a 3 year period

Comment: Well, in that case why not just put it in a Java method?
You can put it in a separate helper class, as a static method like `static Map<String, String> getCountryCodes()`. In case you decide to switch to a database or a config file you just change this code to read that file and pass the content, while the other way around is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try with simply enum for this, this is very effective and easy to maintain.

Example:

```
public enum Country {
    ANDORRA("AD"),
    AFGHANISTAN("AF"),
    ...;

    private String code;

    private Country(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static String findCountryCode(String country) {
        return valueOf(country.toUpperCase()).getCode();
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}


public class CountryTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetCode() throws Exception {
        assertThat(Country.findCountryCode("Andorra")).isEqualTo("AD");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I'm not fully sure from your question which way the mapping should go, or if you need to be able to do lookups both ways. The following assumes that you are looking up country code as the value by the key of country name.

In my experience, number 3 is the best option. In a lot of system architectures you would have to redeploy the application if you need to change hard coded mappings.

I have seen from your comments to the first answer that your mappings are only likely to change once every 3 years or so. However, you can't guarantee that; requirements can change, and so too can international relations.

Your reservations towards number 3 was that

> that would work but could also make the rest of the configuration options harder to find since the other types of data in the configuration table are relatively small and cohesive.

The solution to this point is to have a well defined and clear naming convention for keys in the configuration database. You could, for instance, use multiple levels of prefixes in the key name to narrow down the intended scope/place of use of the configuration values. For example:

```
general.translation.countrycodes.Andorra
```